# Can AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile be loaded from database?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, servicehost

I'm working on a WCF host by using `ServiceHost` and dynamically creating several application domains to keep my services up. I'm also planning to keep my assemblies on database and load them by using `Assembly.Load(byte[])`

But now I stumbled on a problem: how to load my *configuration file* (aka `*.dll.config`) from database and pass it to my new domain? My prototype uses `AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile` and load it from file system, but it will not exist physically on disk.

There is any way to load that configuration file from a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you storing application settings in that configuration file, or are you looking to customize the CLR's behavior e.g. using settings in the  section?

I'm afraid that either way the `ConfigurationManager` and `Configuration` classes in the BCL use files exclusively. However, application settings are nothing more than XML-serialized objects, so you can easily roll your own configuration manager around them (I've done this on a couple of projects).

Finally, you can generate a temporary configuration file from your `byte[]`, store it on disk, create the AppDomain off of it, and delete it when the AppDomain is gone.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot this question. I came across your last suggestion for temporary configuration files a few months ago, but thanks for your interest in answer old questions!